# check for seasonality

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, seasonality

I am quite new to forecasting and I am currently checking for seasonality. I have already checked for stationarity with the Dickey-Fuller test and didn't find one. I have used  seasonal decomposition in Python for period = 5 days. It seems to me that there is seasonality, or am i completely wrong?

[image: seasonality]

This is the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation function below:
[image: acf]

Comment: Why 5? Usually is there is daily data then the pulse would be maybe weekly so 7.

Comment: @Tylerr - perhaps 5 working days in a week

Comment: Yeah, it's because of the working days

Answer (score 0):

The seasonal pulse is ~+-2.5 which seems relatively *small* compared to the magnitude of the series.  What type of decomposition method are you using?  Decomposition methods will typically give you squiggly lines for seasonality no matter what.  Which is fine in general since it doesn't impose too much error as the seasonality usually gets averaged closer to 0 if there is **no** seasonality(looks like that's what is happening here).

There are way better ways to tell if you seasonality such as various seasonality tests or plots to review like acf or kruskal or looking at fourier spikes.  Of course visually inspecting the decomposition is useful as well but you need to pay special attention to the magnitude of seasonality and not just see squiggly lines as evidence.

On the other hand by just reviewing it looks like there *could* be some seasonality but it also looks like there are quite a few large drops that might add a ton of noise to this. Specifically the period between november and jan looks like it is fairly regular but the large drops to 0 right at november and in october will mess things up.  What are these drops?  Are they some events or holidays or something you could control for?  Might clear things up a lot.  Once you control for them then you can try reviewing the seasonality again.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is an additive decomposition. As for the large drops, i am not sure why they occurred tbh. I edited my post and put the acf ,pacf.

Comment: Additive for what algorithm though?  What function are you calling from statsmodels or whatever library you are using.

Comment: from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose    
                s = seasonal_decompose(df, period = 5)

Comment: Yeah so it is using a 'naive' method to decompose and the documentation itself even recommends other methods: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.html#seasonal_decompose . You could try strl decomposition and see if that gives clearer decomposition results. With that said it does look like you have seasonality based on the other plots provided.